# Using MATLAB instead of HSPICE

Tags: matlab, hspice

I need to run a big circuit for thousands of times. Therefore, I am looking for a fast way.

I was wondering if MATLAB has any toolbox that can be used instead of HSPICE.
When I searched online, I saw people mentioning "SimPowerSystems", but I did not use it yet.

For huge number of circuit simulations, is it better to use MATLAB or HSPICE? (in terms of timing and functionalities)

What are the differences?
Which one is faster?
Can I measure voltages, currents, power, ... as I can do in HSPICE?
Will I have the same output files?

Comment: You are wanting comparison of two pieces of software at the top of their field and state which is better than the other Saber or simulink. The real question why isn't hspice doing what you want and what makes you think MATLAB will (it can, easily but it does things differently and different might not give you what you want)

Comment: @JonRB 
Thanks for your response. I have a circuit with  ~400 nodes for now, but may increase up to ~10000 nodes. For each of them, I need to run it thousands of times. I am looking for a way to speed up the process. I was not sure if HSPICE is the best choice.

Comment: I am sure this is a very interesting question. There are some Matab PSpice integration in the File Exchange which would be worth to see.